# deploying app on iPads without connecting each device

Tags: ios

i worked on an app which shouldn't be released to the public and become available on the app store; it's an app for an event where iPads will be on stands for visitors. However, i was think of a way to distribute the app on all the devices we will have without plugging each one of them. i was thinking maybe sending the app for approval and then download it through promo codes on the devices and don't release the app. Does anyone have a better idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want ad hoc over-the-air (OTA) distribution.

http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TestFlight app and homepage

Answer (score 1):

You could use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com), which allows you to register the devices and upload an AdHoc version which they can download from the TestFlight servers.